# excel vba product equals zero

Tags: vba, excel, zero

I am currently working on my second VBA project and I can't seem to find my error.

It is a userform with multiple textboxes and comboboxes which I put into textboxes.
I try to multiply some textboxes and put the result in another textbox which should then be saved into a cell on the worksheet. My problem is that the result of the multiplication always results in zero. I already converted the textboxes into Double type so it should be fine to calculate with the numbers.

Maybe someone else can find the mistake in my code?

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim Leerzeile As Long
Dim Produkt As double

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
With sheet

If tboxEinwaageCharge.Visible = True Then
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 7).Value = tboxEinwCh.Value  
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 8).Value = tboxVol.Value        
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 9).Value = cboxVerd.Value      
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 10).Value = tboxCh1.Value            
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 11).Value = tboxCh2.Value            
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 12).Value = tboxCh3.Value            
     .Cells(Leerzeile + 1, 13).Value = tboxCh4.Value            

     .Cells(Leerzeile, 7).Value = tboxEinw.Value             
     .Cells(Leerzeile, 8).Value = tboxVol.Value              
     .Cells(Leerzeile, 9).Value = cboxVerd.Value           
     .Cells(Leerzeile, 10).Value = tboxKol1.Value                
     .Cells(Leerzeile, 11).Value = tboxKol2.Value                
     .Cells(Leerzeile, 12).Value = tboxKol3.Value                
     .Cells(Leerzeile, 13).Value = tboxKol4.Value                

     Produkt = CDbl(tboxEinw.value) * CDbl(cboxVerd.value) * CDbl(tboxVol.value)

      tboxLZZ.Value = (((cdbl(tboxKol1.value) / Produkt) / 10) + ((cdbl(tboxKol2.value) / Produkt) / 10) + ((cdbl(tboxKol3.value) / Produkt) / 10) + ((cdbl(tboxKol4.value) / Produkt) / 10)) / 4
     tboxLZZMW.Value = cdbl(tboxLZZ.value)
```

I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: use the value not the text.....

Comment: You should also have `Dim sheet As Worksheet` - no need for `Object` because you already know what *it is*

Comment: I applied both tips and I hope I used them correctly. I still get an error

Comment: `Produkt` is defined as `Long` and looking at `CDbl` function used to convert text maybe it should be defined as `Double`, but it is only a guess. There is no sample input in the question body.

Comment: @BrakNicku Thank you very much! It worked with defining it as double.